# A function on a domain $D$ has a primitive on $D$ but is not analytic on $D$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it possible that a function on a domain $D$ has a primitive on $D$ but is not analytic on $D$? 
I know that in a Simply Connected Domain, there is no such thing, as having a primitive in an SCD implies being analytic in an SCD. (by Regularity Theorem)

But what about in Multiply Connected Domains or any Domain in general? 
Thank you!

Comment: If $f: D \to \mathbb{C}$ has a primitive $F: D \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $F' = f$, then $F$ is a complex-differentiable function, and so is infinitely differentiable on $D$. In particular, so is $f$.

Comment: Does this hold for any domain $D$?

Comment: It holds for any open set $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Which theorem states it?

Comment: The fact that a complex-differentiable function defined on an open set $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$? I can't remember which theorem states this, it appears in many guises (complex differentiable functions are analytic at every point in their domain, etc etc).

Comment: Okay thank you so much!